# Expand and select node in Ext GWT 3.0 Tree

Tags: java, gxt, uibinder

I've added an accordion layout container with a tree in its first content pane to my layout. No, a requirement calls to expand and select one node when the application is loaded (it's a mockup).

Then I've added this to the constructor of the class, that corresponds with the uibinder layout:

```
widget = uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this);               // everything's bound

accordionLayoutContainer.setActiveWidget(firstPanel);  // OK, expands first pane
tree.getSelectionModel().select(mynode, true);        // no visible effect
tree.setExpanded(mynode, false);                       // no visible effect
```

What's missing here? Do I have to force the layout of "something" after setting the states or is it the wrong place to select and expand nodes?

Comment: are you sure "mynode" is what you expect, and if you are trying to expand the node, tree.setExpanded(mynode, false) seems like the opposite of what you want.

Comment: Good catch - but fortunately just a typo. Thanks, I corrected it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution. The call to `setExpand` has to be deferred until the tree has been attached. So I added an `AttachEvent.Handler` to a *parent widget* - adding it to directly to the tree doesn't work, because the handler is called to early, before the models are registered.

```
widget = uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this);               // everything's bound

accordionLayoutContainer.setActiveWidget(firstPanel);  // OK, expands first pane
accordionLayoutContainer.addAttachHandler(new AttachEvent.Handler() {

  @Override
  public void onAttachOrDetach(AttachEvent event) {
    clientsTree.getSelectionModel().select(mynode, true);
    clientsTree.setExpanded(mynode, true);              
  }
});
```